# Implement Flick Gesture via GestureService from Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app. This app will allow a user to flick a panel up. I want this to work very similarly to the way the lock screen works. When the user 'flicks' the panel up, I want it to automatically, move up accordingly. Does anyone know how to do this? Currently, I have the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="Peru" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <toolkit:GestureListener x:Name="myGridGestureListener" DragStarted="myGridGestureListener_DragStarted" DragDelta="myGridGestureListener_DragDelta" DragCompleted="myGridGestureListener_DragCompleted" Flick="myGridGestureListener_Flick" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform x:Name="bannerGridTransform" Y="5000" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>

private void myGridGestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical)
  {
  }
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get myGrid to smoothly react to the flick gesture accordingly. I figured someone would have already implemented this, however, apparently, I'm wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/06/a-gesture-driven-windows-phone-to-do-application/). It's not exactly what you need but it's very similar. You should be able to modify it to work vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Hey where do I get the ToolKit for Windows phone 8 gestures

Comment: Ashwin N Bhanushali, look at my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148985/implement-flick-gesture-via-gestureservice-from-windows-phone-8/18948263#18948263

Answer (score 1):

Gesture Listener is deprecated in Windows Phone 8. When you download the latest toolkit source. It contains a sample toolkit app for window phone 8. When you click the gestures, it throws a dialog which says

> The GestureListener is now obsolete in windows phone 8, as the built
>   in manipulation and gesture events now have functional parity with it.
>   This sample and the sample code demonstrated how to use the
>   manipulation and gesture events for purposes for which one previously
>   would have used the GestureListener

Answer (score 1):

If someone need to implement gestures in Windows Phone 8 - look at this https://github.com/PedroLamas/WPtoolkit/blob/master/PhoneToolkitSample8/Samples/GestureSample.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't as trivial as a couple of lines of code on SO since you have to account for the pan while you are holding down the screen and the flick which needs to seamlessly continue on from the pan when the user lifts their finger. A great example of this is actually a darts game since you want the dart to move while you are dragging and then fly off when you release (the flick).

You can find a great example with source code at http://windowsphone7developerguide.blograby.com/darts-gesture-listener-flick-gesture/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use toolkit gesture listener anymore. You can use in built manipulation events. Here is the sample:-
http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PhoneToolkitSample8/Samples/GestureSample.xaml.cs