# Why does Windows 8 Phone Flick Gesture only work on upper half of the screen?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I successfully implemented the `flick` (aka `slide`, `swipe`) gesture on my `Windows 8 Phone App` following the instructions [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148985/implement-flick-gesture-via-gestureservice-from-windows-phone-8), but for some reason, it is only recognized on the upper half of the screen.

I tried this with the simulator and on an actual dev device (`Nokia Lumia 520`) and had the same results.

My app is using **ApplicationBar** and the flick gesture coincidentally starts to recognize motion where the **ApplicationBar** flyover ends (at full extension).

The image that listens for Gestures also has a `tap` event, and that one works fine across the whole image (upper/lower halves of the screen).

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: 
Here is some code that I tried by creating a blank Page and still not having any luck. The area where the "FLICK" gesture is recognized is constrained to the upper left of the phone screen (both in the simnulator and actual device).

Here is my code (CS):

**FlickTest.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
namespace Windows_8_Phone_App
{
    public partial class FlickTest : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public FlickTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void image_GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (titulo.Text == "Foo")
            {
                titulo.Text = "Bar";            
            }
            else {
                titulo.Text = "Foo";
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

**And the XAML code:**

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Windows_8_Phone_App.FlickTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"          
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="Landscape"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="titulo" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Image x:Name="imagen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="309" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="694" Source="/Assets/AppBar/basecircle.png" Stretch="Fill">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="image_GestureListener_Flick" />
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Image>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: You don't by chance have another object higher in the tree that's only toggling `Opacity` instead of `Visibility` to show it that would be intercepting the hittest would you? Like say a keyboard or some other object?

Comment: I am only using Opacity for the ApplicationSettings flyover, but it's at 0.65, but that flyover is collapsed, unless you tap over it, which opens the whole thing.

Comment: I am going to create a blank project and just slowly recreate my structure of layers to see if I can catch the culprit (i.e. add an image as the only object in the grid, enable flick gesture, test and see if the whole screen is recognized, then start adding layers).

Comment: OK, I tried creating a new page, and still no luck. The "FLICK" area that is recognized by the Gesture Listener is constrained to a rectangular area in the upper left of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pain, the problem is that the **Windows Phone Toolkit** has a known issue and it doesn't work in landscape mode ([see this entry](https://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/11329)).

So in the mean time, while that gets fixed, I am looking for alternatives...

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this problem. GestureListener does not work in landscape mode (as alejandrormz wrote). :(

But, I have a solution -> built in Manipulation and Gesture event. :)
Its easy to implement. Best sample code: [GitHub](https://github.com/PedroLamas/WPtoolkit/blob/master/PhoneToolkitSample8/Samples/GestureSample.xaml.cs)

Hope this helps.